# Angular directive scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
  <tab page="book"> </tab>
  <tab page="dial"> </tab>
  <tab page="groupe"> </tab>
  <tab page="log"> </tab>
  <tab page="star"> </tab>
```

As you can see i have a directive named **tab**, and this **tab** have an attribute **page**,

i need to change the **templateUrl** based on the value of  **page** attribute

> if the **page** value is `page="abc"` then the **templateUrl** should be   `templateUrl: 'tab/abc.html',`

here is my directive code

```
contactBook.directive('tab', function() {
    let m = 'tab/default.html';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            page: '@',
        },
        templateUrl: m,
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            m = "tab/" + scope.page + ".html";      
        },
    };
});
```

is this logically possible..? or any alternative methode to done this..?

Comment: Try with page: '=' instead of page: '@', that will allow you to immediately use the attribute value inside link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
    return "tab/" + attrs.page + ".html" || 'tab/default.html';
},
```

Comment: Thanks  it solve my problem , but i have no idea where the varibale elem,attrs  came from ,

Comment: element is where the directive was called and attribute is object associated with that element. For reference you can also check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2):

```
contactBook.directive('tab', function() {
    let m = 'tab/default.html';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            page: '@',
        },
        templateUrl: m,
        link: function(element, attributes) {
            m = "tab/" + attributes.page + ".html";    // attributes.page can access attribute value
        },
    };
});
```

You are isolating scope for tab directive and you have a binding

```
 scope: {
          page: '@',
     }
```

if your are passing just a `string` on parent scope to directive then use

```
<tab page={{book}}> </tab>
```

but if you want to pass an object from parent scope to directive then

```
<tab page="book"> </tab>
```

then in your directive

```
  scope: {
              page: '=',
         }
```